# Message successfully sent with ajax and php but no email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I found a template and everything works fine, but I don't know what is going on..
here is HTML code

```html
<form action="#" id="contactform" class="animform"><!-- Contact form -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="name" class="flabel">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
      <div class="indicate-name"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="email" class="flabel">E-mail</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
      <div class="indicate-email"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="message" class="flabel">Enter your message</label>
      <textarea name="message" cols="88" rows="6" id="message"></textarea>
      <div class="indicate-message"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send your message" class="submit">Send your message</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form><!-- /Contact form -->
```

and here's jQ code

```js
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    (function () {
        var MIN_NAME_LENGTH = 2,
            MIN_TEXT_LENGTH = 5,
            NAME_ERROR_TEXT = 'Minimum 2 characters',
            EMAIL_ERROR_TEXT = 'Please enter correct e-mail',
            MSG_ERROR_TEXT = 'Minimum 5 characters',
            ERROR_CLASS_NAME = 'error',
            SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME = 'ok',

            $contactForm = $('#contactform'),
            $formSuccess = $('.form-success'),
            $nameField = $contactForm.find('#name'),
            $emailField = $contactForm.find('#email'),
            $textField = $contactForm.find('#message');

        function init() {
            _bindEvents();
        }

        function _bindEvents() {
            $('.new-message').click(function() {
                $contactForm.delay(600).slideDown(1000);
                $formSuccess.slideUp(500);
            });

            $nameField.live('blur', _nameValidate);
            $emailField.live('blur', _emailValidate);
            $textField.live('blur', _textValidate);

            $contactForm.live('submit', function () {
                var status = _nameValidate(true) & _emailValidate(true) & _textValidate(true);
                if (!!status) {
                    _submitForm();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

        function _submitForm() {
   var data = {
     name: $("#form_name").val(),
     email: $("#form_email").val(),
     message: $("#msg_text").val()
    };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "contact.php",
                data:{
                    'name': $nameField.val(),
                    'email': $emailField.val(),
                    'message': $textField.val()
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg === 'SEND') {
                        $contactForm.slideUp(1000);
                        $formSuccess.delay(1000).slideDown(500);
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            // clear form value, shown labels
                            $nameField.val('');
                            $emailField.val('');
                            $textField.val('');
                            $contactForm.find( 'label[for="'+$nameField.attr( 'id' )+'"]').css( 'display', 'block').css( 'opacity', 1 );
                            $contactForm.find( 'label[for="'+$emailField.attr( 'id' )+'"]').css( 'display', 'block').css( 'opacity', 1 );
                            $contactForm.find( 'label[for="'+$textField.attr( 'id' )+'"]').css( 'display', 'block').css( 'opacity', 1 );
                        }, 1000 );
                    }
                    else {
                        $contactForm.prepend( '<div class="error">' + msg + '</div>' );
                    }
                },
                error: function( t, errorStatus ) {
                    $contactForm.prepend( '<div class="error">' + errorStatus + '</div>' );
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".error,.success").remove();
                }
            });
        }

        function _nameValidate(errIfEmpty) {
            var $memo = $contactForm.find('.indicate-name'),
                val = $nameField.val().replace(/\s+$/g, ''),
                result = false;
            errIfEmpty = errIfEmpty === true ? true : false;

            if (!errIfEmpty && val.length === 0) {
                $memo
                    .text('')
                    .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                    .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
            } else {
                if (val.length >= MIN_NAME_LENGTH) {
                    $memo
                        .text('')
                        .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME);
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    $memo
                        .text(NAME_ERROR_TEXT)
                        .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        function _emailValidate(errIfEmpty) {
            var $memo = $contactForm.find('.indicate-email'),
                val = $emailField.val().replace(/\s+$/g, ''),
                regExp = /^.+@.+\..{2,6}$/i,
                result = false;
            errIfEmpty = errIfEmpty === true ? true : false;

            if (!errIfEmpty && val.length === 0) {
                $memo
                    .text('')
                    .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                    .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
            } else {
                if (regExp.test(val)) {
                    $memo
                        .text('')
                        .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME);
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    $memo
                        .text(EMAIL_ERROR_TEXT)
                        .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        function _textValidate(errIfEmpty) {
            var $memo = $contactForm.find('.indicate-message'),
                val = $textField.val().replace(/\s+$/g, ''),
                result = false;
            errIfEmpty = errIfEmpty === true ? true : false;

            if (!errIfEmpty && val.length === 0) {
                $memo
                    .text('')
                    .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                    .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
            } else {
                if (val.length >= MIN_TEXT_LENGTH) {
                    $memo
                        .text('')
                        .removeClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME);
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    $memo
                        .text(MSG_ERROR_TEXT)
                        .removeClass(SUCCESS_CLASS_NAME)
                        .addClass(ERROR_CLASS_NAME);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        init();
    })();
});
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php 

    $to  =   'myEmail@anyEmail.com'; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Message from site";
    $theMessage = $_POST['message'];

    $message = "This message from \n\n Name: " . $name . "\n\n";
    $message .= "Enquiries: " . $theMessage . "\n\n";

    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
        echo "SEND";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }

//print_r(error_get_last());?>
```

The form does say success, but still not receiving the emails! any ideas?

P.S. I tried two different Emails "hotmail" and "ymail", but the two of them didn't receive anything..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Send email trought php need a smtp configuration. 
The mail() function return true if he successfull order to the system to send the mail. 
But if you have trouble with your smtp, the mail will never arrive.
Then you will have to format your headers correctly http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php

Comment: updated my headers to :  `$headers  = "From: $from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";
  $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`   but nothing happens